# Use of image magick compare command - how to catch the integer result of different pixels?

Tags: compare, imagemagick

I am using this command line

```
compare -metric AE -fuzz 5% $OLD_JPG_ProcessFILE $JPG_ProcessFILE  /tmp/JPG_PathFullFillName.gif
```

The command does work and throws me the result as an integer number of different pixels into the next command line of Putty - but I can't assign this integer value to a bash variable ...!

How to do that?

This command

```
    var=$(compare -metric AE -fuzz 5% $OLD_JPG_ProcessFILE $JPG_ProcessFILE  /tmp/JPG_PathFullFillName.gif)
```

does not work, $var remains empty ...!

Thanks in advance and BR

Answer (score 2):

Testing around I have found the answer by appending "null: 2>&1" :

```
    Pixel_Difference=$(compare -metric AE -fuzz 5% $OLD_JPG_ProcessFILE $JPG_ProcessFILE  /tmp/JPG_PathFullFillName.gif null: 2>&1)
```

Works fine!

But why - what is the "magic" behind with "null: 2>&1" ???

Comment: null: suppresses the output image. 2>&1 is because imagemagick writes to stderr and to get the result you need to push it to stdout

Comment: Thanks a lot - very helpful! Understood! But ... When null:  surpresses the output (image), isn't all output surpressed (also stdout) ? Or is mapping stderr to stdoud a reactivating (an exception) ???

Comment: text information not the image goes to stderr.